# gdal_calc.py --NoDataValue=none error

Tags: gdal

This is the version of GDAL that I am running

`dnf list gdal`

```
Last metadata expiration check: 0:10:43 ago on Fri 20 Jan 2023 08:40:35 AM EST.

Installed Packages
gdal.x86_64                                                                                                       3.5.2-1.fc37
```

When executing the gdal_calc.py command.

`gdal_calc.py -A "${BASE_DIRECTORY}/S2A-TCI.tif" --NoDataValue=none --allBands=A -B "${BASE_DIRECTORY}/S2A-CLOUD-MASK_20m.tif" --outfile=${BASE_DIRECTORY}/S2A-CLOUDFREE-TCI.tif --co PHOTOMETRIC=RGB --calc=(B==1)*A+(B!=1)*255`

The program returns the following error.

`gdal_calc.py: error: argument --NoDataValue: invalid float value: 'none'`

Why am I getting the error when using the `--NoDataValue=none parameter`?

Runs fine without it, but sets the `nodata` value to `255`

Any ideas?

The docs state:

> --NoDataValue=
>
> Output NoDataValue (default datatype specific value).
>
> To indicate not setting a NoDataValue use --NoDataValue=none (GDAL >= 3.3)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I believe that you have too old version. Notice that the gdal_calc.py is a Python script and you may have an older version of that hanging in your system. You can find the newest version from GitHub https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/swig/python/gdal-utils/osgeo_utils/gdal_calc.py.